# Extracting coefficients with all information from gls output in R

Tags: r, modeling

I need to get the coefficients along with their SEs, t-values and p-values from gls output in *R*.

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary,
       correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))

summary(fm1)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: follicles ~ sin(2 * pi * Time) + cos(2 * pi * Time) 
  Data: Ovary 
   AIC      BIC    logLik
  1571.455 1590.056 -780.7273

Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 | Mare 
 Parameter estimate(s):
  Phi 
0.7532079 

Coefficients:
                   Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)        12.216398 0.6646437 18.380373  0.0000
sin(2 * pi * Time) -2.774712 0.6450478 -4.301561  0.0000
cos(2 * pi * Time) -0.899605 0.6975383 -1.289685  0.1981

 Correlation: 
               (Intr) s(*p*T
sin(2 * pi * Time)  0.000       
cos(2 * pi * Time) -0.294  0.000

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.41180365 -0.75405234 -0.02923628  0.63156880  3.16247697 

Residual standard error: 4.616172 
Degrees of freedom: 308 total; 305 residual
```

I'd highly appreciate if someone help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: get them where exactly? They show up in the summary, do you want to export this, or use them as input for another function? The question, as it stands, is rather unclear.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe: I just want them to extract from this summary and want to use in sweave file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
> cs <- as.data.frame(summary(fm1)$tTable)
> cs
                        Value Std.Error   t-value      p-value
(Intercept)        12.2163982 0.6646437 18.380373 2.618737e-51
sin(2 * pi * Time) -2.7747122 0.6450478 -4.301561 2.286284e-05
cos(2 * pi * Time) -0.8996047 0.6975383 -1.289685 1.981371e-01
> cs$t
[1] 18.380373 -4.301561 -1.289685
> cs$p
[1] 2.618737e-51 2.286284e-05 1.981371e-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the values above for some kind of table, a solution is relatively simple.

```
sumfm1 <- summary(fm1)

sumfm1$tTable

                       Value Std.Error   t-value      p-value
(Intercept)        12.2163982 0.6646437 18.380373 2.618737e-51
sin(2 * pi * Time) -2.7747122 0.6450478 -4.301561 2.286284e-05
cos(2 * pi * Time) -0.8996047 0.6975383 -1.289685 1.981371e-01
```

More generally, if you call the `str()` function on any R object, you can normally (with a bit of trial and error) figure out how to extract the results you need.

EDIT: if you need it to go into a sweave file, then call xtable on the object above, and all should be good.